# how is mysql 200 connections limit applied?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building an ecommerce site hosted on godaddy shared hosting and I saw that only 200  database connections are allowed.
I am using Codeigniter framework for the site and I have 2 databases for the project.

Database 1 for storing sessions only with a user with read, write, update and delete privileges

Database 2 rest of tables needed for site, with a read only user.

Since 1 website visitor will be connecting to 2 databases does this mean that I can only have 100 visitoras at a time? Since each one will be using 2 connections.

Or can someone explain the 200 connections limit please.

Comment: You may only be able to have 50 users in theory. Depends on your code (the closes). Get about 20 users on it and issue a `show processlist;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Drew said, it depends. Limits exist everywhere (hardware, software, bandwidth etc). GoDaddy has it's own limitations ([not only to database connections](https://gr.godaddy.com/help/how-many-visitors-can-view-my-site-at-once-3206)). Optimizing your code can help you take the maximum of the web-server and database servers.

For example if your code uses the database connection for 1 second to each database, you can serve **100 visitors** per second. If you use it for 0.2 of a sec then you can serve **500 visitors every second**.

Optimization is necessary especially on heavy web applications. Maybe you could organize your app so it does not need connecting to both databases for every request (this would double the available connectios per time fraction). Optimizing the SQL queries and minimizing JOINing tables will help your app too (also it will make it run faster).

Finally you can use caching, so you will not have your server constructing the same content again and again. This is not a full list of all optimizations you can do, but a start point to do your research and planning. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you Geo Halkiadakis!!